# Script not running but commands execute on terminal with python (gnomekeyring.IOError)

Tags: scripting, terminal, python, gnome-keyring

I am trying to unlock one keyring using the library `gnomekeyring` in python.

I have written my script, but it throws me the error `gnomekeyring.IOError`. However, if I run python at the terminal and write each line of code, I get the expected result.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gnomekeyring as gk
dk = gk.get_default_keyring_sync()
gk.lock_all_sync()
gk.unlock_sync(dk, 'my_pass')
```

At terminal I don't write `#!/usr/bin/python`, but with the rest of lines unlock the default keyring.

I am new with Linux (Mint 18), and I am a bit lost with the terminal. Any help will be appreciated!